# Android layout anomaly - actual layout not complying with Android Studio appearance.

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to write an application with two separate views of graphical data - one as an X-Y graph. and the other an X vs T graph.  I want the two to be arranged vertically, with the  X-Y graph on top.  I have written an extension to the View class which manages the plotting, and that is not the problem.

I initially used a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCCCFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="clearCanvas"
            android:text="@string/btn1Text"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="startPlot"
            android:text="@string/btn2Text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <co.android.bmd.chaoswithtime.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/plot_canvas"
        android:layout_width="1000px"
        android:layout_height="1000px"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <co.android.bmd.chaoswithtime.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/trend_canvas"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        tools:layout_below="@id/plot_canvas"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:layout_width="1000px" />

</RelativeLayout
```

According to the layout shown in Android Studio, this should give the required result:
[image]
X-T view overlaying the XY view:

[image]

I've tried a number of variants to get the alignment sorted out, but the only way to do it was to add a hefty top margin to the X-T view - not very satisfactory.

I can get what I want using a LinearLayout, but cannot figure out why the Relativelayout does not work (and why there is a difference between the preview in Android Studio and the emulated result from the same package.  (The emulated result actually comes up on the real device as well.)

Can anyone come up with an explanation?

Comment: Why tools:layout_below and not android:layout_below?

Comment: That was what I got from the layout package in AS - it has fixed the drawing order. But now the two graphics panels are left-justified instead of central.

Comment: Use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: I can manage to get the layout I want - but my original question still remains - Why does Android Studio preview not match the layout on the device?

Answer (score 0):

You have passed width and height in pixels, that means it's content and when you run your code it takes only 1000 pixels  in screen.

Better is that you should use `LinearLayout` as parent of your custom view and use weight and `weightSum`. And pass  `match_parent` width and height to `LinearLayout`.

you can try with below xml. this could help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCCCFF"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="clearCanvas"
            android:text="@string/btn1Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
            android:onClick="startPlot"
            android:text="@string/btn2Text" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <co.android.bmd.chaoswithtime.CanvasView
            android:id="@+id/plot_canvas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <co.android.bmd.chaoswithtime.CanvasView
            android:id="@+id/trend_canvas"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            tools:layout_below="@id/plot_canvas"1
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout
```

Comment: At this stage I'm using a fixed layout with a single target - once I get the fundamental issue sorted. I'll look at adding in code to cope with different targets.

Comment: @user1815293 please check above xml and try with this.